# KStream.processValues() - getting a null state store from FixedKeyProcessor

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have the following topology which uses `processValues()` method to combine streams DSL with Processor Api. I'm adding a state store here.

```java
KStream<String, SecurityCommand> securityCommands =
            builder.stream(
                    "security-command",
                    Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), JsonSerdes.securityCommand()));

StoreBuilder<KeyValueStore<String, UserAccountSnapshot>> storeBuilder =
            Stores.keyValueStoreBuilder(
                    Stores.persistentKeyValueStore("user-account-snapshot"),
                    Serdes.String(),
                    JsonSerdes.userAccountSnapshot());

builder.addStateStore(storeBuilder);

securityCommands.processValues(() -> new SecurityCommandProcessor(), Named.as("security-command-processor"), "user-account-snapshot")
                .processValues(() -> new UserAccountSnapshotUpdater(), Named.as("user-snapshot-updater"), "user-account-snapshot")
                .to("security-event", Produced.with(
                                                Serdes.String(),
                                                JsonSerdes.userAccountEvent()));
```

The `SecurityCommandProcessor` code follows:

```java
class SecurityCommandProcessor implements FixedKeyProcessor<String, SecurityCommand, UserAccountEvent> {

    private KeyValueStore<String, UserAccountSnapshot> kvStore;
    private FixedKeyProcessorContext context;

    @Override
    public void init(FixedKeyProcessorContext context) {
        this.kvStore = (KeyValueStore<String, UserAccountSnapshot>) context.getStateStore("user-account-snapshot");
        this.context = context;
    }
    ...
}
```

The problem is that `context.getStateStore("user-account-snapshot")` returns **null**.

I tried doing nearly the same code, by using the obsolete `transformValues()` and I'm able to get the state store. The problem is with `processValues()`. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Have you been able to find a solution to your problem? When I use processValues(), I receive the same error. There are no issues when I use the process() method.

Comment: No, I switched to the obsolete `transformValues()`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you're using a lambda instance for the [FixedKeyProcessorSupplier](https://javadoc.io/static/org.apache.kafka/kafka-streams/3.3.1/org/apache/kafka/streams/processor/api/FixedKeyProcessorSupplier.html). When the processor needs access to a state store, you'll need to override the `stores` method, which returns `null` when it's not overridden. The `FixedKeyProcessorSupplier` extends the [ConnectedStoreProvider](https://javadoc.io/static/org.apache.kafka/kafka-streams/3.3.1/org/apache/kafka/streams/processor/ConnectedStoreProvider.html#stores--) interface.

So you'll need to provide a concrete instance of the processor supplier.

Let me know how it goes.

HTH,
Bill

Comment: Thank you. It remains the same. The following is my argument for "processValues".
.processValues(new TickConsolidatorFixedKeyProcessorSupplier(storeBuilder)). In addition, the processor supplier overrides the store method.

Comment: Yeah, it's looking like a bug right now - I've filed a Jira  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-14388 for this and should have a PR soon

Comment: To close the loop, a fix (https://github.com/apache/kafka/pull/12861) for this issue was merged today and will be available with 3.4.0 and 3.3.2

Comment: Thank you for reporting and fixing this issue! I've been running into it apparently as well. Do you have an idea for when 3.3.2 will show up in the Maven Central? (The release was tagged in GitHub 6 days ago last week more than 6 days ago)

Comment: 3.3.2 should show up in Maven central any day now, I'd say be the end of this week.

Comment: Found this https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Release+plan+3.3.2 with release dates being "December 2022/January 2023"

Comment: 3.3.2 is out! But there seems to be an incompatible change (in a patch build?) in kafka.utils.TestUtils so that I have to wait for spring-kafka-test upgrade :( Will probably switch back to transformer API.

Comment: spring-kafka-test:3.0.2 fixes my problem fully